# Excel- copying cells using drop down

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to extract particular cells from sheet 1 to sheet 2 depending on a dropdown list in sheet 2. Here is a catch, i need the whole cell with the formulae and data validation in those cells and not just values. Can it be done?
For example, i have a dropdown list in sheet 1 A2 and using a drop down in sheet 2 i need to copy the Cell A2 from sheet 1 to b3 of sheet 2 such that the b3 of sheet 2 should have the drop down list that was originally in sheet1 A2. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

How did you create the List?
If you create the List with Data Validation, you can try this workaround:
Copy the cell from Sheet1 to Sheet2, and change the cell list source in Sheet2, then you can copy and paste the list from Sheet2 to other Sheets:

[image]